# Embedded cert not being included in HttpClient request (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I am trying to send an SSL certificate to an external API in order to authenticate with their service. I'm getting the error: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

I talked to the company hosting the API and they said they changed their service to accept any SSL cert just to ensure I was actually sending an SSL cert and I got the same error so it seems like the SSL cert isn't being included in the request.

```
var clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(GetEmbeddedCert());

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
     return client.PostAsync(_plugin.EndPoint.ToString().Trim(),
     new StringContent(hl7)).Result;                
}
```

I use an embedded cert with Build Action set to "Embedded Resource":

```
private X509Certificate2 GetEmbeddedCert()
    {
        using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
       .GetManifestResourceStream(GetType(), "mycert.cer"))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            for (int idx = 0; idx < stream.Length; idx++)
                bytes[idx] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();

            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
            cert.Import(bytes);
            return cert;
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas why the SSL cert is not being sent or why I'm getting the above error?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try using certificate with web browser? Does it work?

Comment: For some reason that certificate isn't in the list of certs that popup when I navigate to the url in a browser but I used a different one and I get a 405 method not allowed @MarkoKotar